# Disable form fields and buttons when javascript is disabled by browser

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am working on a project based on play framework. I am displaying an error message "Please enable javascript in your browser" using the ***noscript*** tag. But, I also want to disable all the form fields and buttons if the javascript is disabled in the browser.

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to take it the other way. All the buttons and input should be disabled by default. Then if JS is enabled, run a script to enable the inputs and button (remove all disabled attributes).-- Because without JS... You simply can do nothing.

Comment: If you are able to display a message that javascript is not enabled and that your site depends on it, then you should be able to not show the form at all until javascript is enabled by the user. Even with all controls of a form disabled, if a person is tech savvy enough, they can go into the HTML and enable controls and buttons themselves, potentially still submitting a form with whatever data they want to put into the form.

Comment: @RyanWilson: As a *tech savvy enough person*, I would simply enable the JS on my browser...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I was referring more to people who have a malicious intent. Not a normal user. Perhaps the javascript is used for validation purposes.

Comment: @RyanWilson: I know... But trying to hack a website with the JS off seems way harder to me, don't you think? So if the website has no big security issue with JS on... What can be an added risk with JS off?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It's an interesting conversation. I suppose it all comes down to how secure the site is. As I don't have that information, I can't say one way or the other. Your point is well taken. I was just adding my 2 cents as to something to think about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly to the concept of "mobile-first" where the desing of a website is made for mobiles and the @media rules are addded for larger screens...

Here you will write the HTML as "non-JS first".

Add the `disabled` attribute everywhere in the markup... And also add a meaningful class like `nonJSdisabled` to it.

So if JS is enabled, this will remove the `disabled` attributes where it needs to be removed:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".nonJSdisabled").forEach(function(item){
  item.setAttribute("disabled", false)
})
```

Same with jQuery:

```
$(".nonJSdisabled").prop("disabled", false);
```

OR

```
$(".nonJSdisabled").attr("disabled", false);
```

You do not need anything special to know if JS is enabled. So there is no `if` condition at all. Just make sure the DOM is fully loaded to run that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to allow the form to work without JavaScript first and foremost.

However, if you are insistent on using JS to maintain the usability of any site, the best thing you can do is to put the `disabled` attr in all your form elements by default, e.g:
`<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" disabled="disabled"/>`

I have seen and tried using just `disabled` without the `="disabled"` in the past but it's never worked 100% for me when using JS to add/remove it consistently. Plus having the `=` give the attr an actual value.

Then, use your JS skilz to remove the `disabled` attr from every form field.

If everything is disabled by default, you are achieving your goal of restricting your site for non-js users :)